# Ajax Control Toolkits não roda na Web App Azure

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-azure, ajaxtoolkit

Tenho uma aplicação `WebForms` `.aspx` com controles Ajax do componente `Ajax Control Toolkits`, que roda perfeitamente na máquina local! Mas quando publico no servidor do Azure Web App, os controles não funcionam mesmo fazendo as referências no `Web.config` e copiando a `Dll` na pasta `bin` não roda.

Do lado do cliente tenho o seguinte erro:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: 
WebForm_TexBoxKeyHandler is not defined at 
HTMLInputElement.onkeypress
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=####,1433;
         Initial Catalog=####;
         Integrated Security=False;
         TrustServerCertificate=False;
         User ID=####;
         Password=####;
         Connection Timeout=30" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Autenticacao/Login.aspx" 
             defaultUrl="~/Views/PesquisaProcesso.aspx" timeout="1440" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

  </system.web>
  <location path="~/Autenticacao/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Autenticacao/Registrar.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Autenticacao">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordFormat="Clear" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
             connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" 
             applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="100000000" />
    <pages buffer="true" masterPageFile="~/Site.master" enableEventValidation="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" 
                type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, 
                Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
                PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" 
                compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" 
                type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, 
                Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, 
                Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" 
                compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; 
                /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Referência nas paginas:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema?